# REST API to create and ADD Recipients in DocuSign

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using php for Embedded Signing in DocuSign, I have successfully created the signing url for a template document by adding the recipients manually in the docusign portal, now i'm looking for rest api's to create recipient and add the recipient to the particular template document.

I have searched for the apis in http://iodocs.docusign.com/#, but it is not there, can any one help on this ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Envelopes::create call enables you to include the recipient information at the time that you create the envelope.

Recipient types including signers, people who get a copy of the envelope, people who get a copy of the envelope and acknowledge receipt, etc.

Including the recipients when you create/send the envelope is the easiest way to go. [See this recipe for an example](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/send-multiple-docs).

You can also add recipients to a template. In this case, when you create the template, you are specifying *roles*. Then, later, when you make an API Envelopes::create call that uses the template, you can provide the names of the people (or signing groups) for each of the roles that you specified in the template. [See this recipe for an example.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email-using-a-template)

Thank you for developing with DocuSign.